# Show what data the site is getting from Facebook login

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I am implementing facebook login on my React project with a Rails backend API.

I would like to know if there is a way to specify what data my site will receive from Facebook as a result of this authentication process.

For now I just want to get data without getting approval from Facebook, which would be emails and public profiles.

According to the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview), I know if I am asking for more, I need Facebook approval as well as a review by the user on the login pop-up. Is there a way to show in the Facebook login window that pops up to show that the data is non-controversial? Or is the only way to have text on my login page to explain that?

The login button is below with the data-scope requiring no Facebook approval.

```
<div className="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-scope="email,public_profile" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

Comment: There is no way for you to place any custom text explanation on the login dialog, no.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the input.